# Как получить JSON из CURL запроса?

Tags: java, json, curl

У меня имеется следующий пример CURL запроса.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header "authorization: Bearer <API token>" 'https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans?name=%239C8LGYQQ'
```

Обычно я делал так:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new RestTemplate().getForObject("https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans?name=%239C8LGYQQ", String.class));
```

Сейчас я должен передавать ещё token и всё остальное. Пробовал передать параметром через url, но всё без успешно.

Подскажите как я могу это сделать. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на библиотеку [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html)

С ней ваш запрос будет выглядет так

```
JSONObject jsonObject = Unirest.get("https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans")
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer" + apiToken)
        .queryString("name", "#9C8LGYQQ")
        .asJson()
        .getBody()
        .getObject();
```

В принципе можно сразу вытащить из ответа нужные данные, но показать как не могу, так как не знаю содержимое объекта.

Comment: Вау!!! Красивое решение, огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: тут скорее, спасибо, создателям Unirest :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans?name=%239C8LGYQQ";
String token = "<API token>";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("", headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.getBody());
```

Comment: Благодарю за Ваш ответ. вы использовали org.springframework.http* ?  у меня ругается IDEA на строку   String response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class);    no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<T> conforms to java.lang.String

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)